# How to create a controlled (with React useState) SVG text field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, input

```html
<div contentEditable>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 300 300'>
    <text x=2 y=40>
      Can this be a text input field?
    </text>
    <text y=80>
      But not this
    </text>
    <text y=110>
      And not this
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The text in the above SVG is editable because it is wrapped in `<div contentEditable>`, however for our use case this is not ideal as is:

- most importantly, we are using React and we'd like the editable text to be controlled in state.
- all text in the above SVG is editable, not just the first text field as is desired
- it is a big buggy, with the cursor going way far to the right

It is possible to create an individually controlled (with React `useState`) SVG text field?

**EDIT:** something along these lines does appear to work:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState('here is some text');

// And Return
return (<>
    <svg>
        <foreignObject x="40" y="40" width="300" height="150">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <FormControl
                    className='modal-input'
                    type='text'
                    value={test}
                    onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)}
                    name='firstname'
                    placeholder='First Name'
                />
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
        ...
```

Where `FormElement` is from react-bootstrap. We are going to keep working with this and see if it fits our use case fully, but so far, so good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed HTML fragments (including React portals for example) in SVG using the [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) tag (which is specifically designed to allow HTML in SVG). BTW I think if you just want to embed some inputs into SVG, doing it using `contenteditable` does not seem to make any sense. Just use normal `<inputs>`

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 300 300'>
  <foreignObject x='0' y='0' width='100' height='100'>
    <div contenteditable>
      Can this be a text input field?
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
  <text y='80'>
    But not this
  </text>
  <text y='110'>
    And not this
  </text>
</svg>
```